# What is .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

I just created a Github repository and was wondering what the `.gitignore` file was for. I started by not creating one, but added one due to the fact that most repositories have one.
Do I need to have one? Can/do I just ignore it, or does it have a use?

Answer (score 200, accepted):

`.gitignore` tells git which files (or patterns) it should ignore. It's usually used to avoid committing transient files from your working directory that aren't useful to other collaborators, such as compilation products, temporary files IDEs create, etc.

You can find the full details [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Comment: So if you create a .gitignore in a new repository on github.com, and then do a git init and git add *.* on your local computer -- not yet connected to .gitignore as it's not yet connected to that repository -- how does this work? Does it take effect when I perform a git commit? Or?

Comment: what is `_._gitignore` used for? is it used only when the `gitignore ` is in a sub Dir.?

Comment: So it remains locally, but does not gets pushed to origin? So if some user downloads github repo, does that secret file gets downloaded it with too?

Comment: What does _ignore_ mean? Who/what/when does the ignore? I know what the **word** ignore means but I don't find a clear description of what ignore means in the context of Git. Obviously the term is totally understandable by people that understand it but anything written to define something for people that don't already know it needs to explain all the terms that have definitions unique to the context.

Comment: @user34660 Ignore means just that - Git will not track changes in the files specified by (the patterns) in the `.gitignore` file. Even if you change them, git won't show them as modified.

Comment: Then what does track mean? You must understand that a beginner might not know if track applies to before/after a commit or before/after a push or to something else. Terms that have significance only in the relevant context need to be defined/explained. I pushed a project to GitHub and got some files that I thought should not go. I am not asking for help with that except it would help me to be certain of what is supposed to happen so I can be sure that what did happen was not supposed to (something is broken) so then I know I need to fix it.

Answer (score 46):

It's a list of files you want git to ignore in your work directory.

Say you're on a Mac and you have .DS_Store files in all your directories.  You want git to ignore them, so you add .DS_Store as a line in .gitignore.  And so on.

The git docs will tell you all you need to know: http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: Your `.DS_Store` scenario finally resonated with me as I guess I wasn't cluing on to this concept because I had not yet needed to use it in a project. Thank you. I ended up using [this](https://gist.github.com/octocat/9257657) as a starting point as I use all different operating systems noting specifically the `# OS generated files #` section.

Comment: I know I am late to this thread, but thank you @AndyLester! I am a novice when it comes to programming and Github. I find many of the answers written to address this type of question are filled with terms the novice might not understand (i.e., compilation products, temporary files IDEs create....what the h@ll are these things!). However, your Mac description is perfect in its elegant simplicity!

Answer (score 26):

When you are doing a commit you do not want accidentally include temporary files or build specific folders. Hence use a `.gitignore` listing out items you want to ignore from committing.

**Also, importantly** `git status` is one of the most frequently used command where you want `git status` to list out the files that have been modified.

You **would want your `git status` list look clean** from unwanted files. For instance, I changed `a.cpp, b.cpp, c.cpp, d.cpp & e.cpp` I want my `git status` to list the following:

```
git status
a.cpp
b.cpp
c.cpp
d.cpp
e.cpp
```

**I dont want `git status`** to list out changed files like this with the intermediary object files & files from the build folder

```
git status
a.cpp
b.cpp
c.cpp
d.cpp
e.cpp
.DS_Store
/build/program.o
/build/program.cmake
```

Hence, to get myself free from `git status` to list out these intermediate temporary files & accidentally committing them into the repo, I should create a `.gitignore` which everyone does. All I need to do list out the files & folders in the `.gitignore` that I want to exclude from committing.

**Following is my `.gitignore` to avoid committing unnecessary files**

```
/*.cmake
/*.DS_Store
/.user
/build
```

Comment: I believe you can use `.gitattributes` to ignore files from `diff`/`status`.

Answer (score 9):

There are files you don't want Git to check in to. Git sees every file in your working copy as one of three things:

1. tracked - a file which has been previously staged or committed;
2. untracked - a file which has not been staged or committed; or
3. ignored - a file which Git has been explicitly told to ignore.

Ignored files are usually built artifacts and machine-generated files that can be derived from your repository source or should otherwise not be committed. Some common examples are:

- dependency caches, such as the contents of `/node_modules` or `/packages`
- compiled code, such as `.o`, `.pyc`, and `.class` files
- build output directories, such as `/bin`, `/out`, or `/target`
- files generated at runtime, such as `.log`, `.lock`, or `.tmp`
- hidden system files, such as `.DS_Store` or `Thumbs.db`
- personal IDE config files, such as `.idea/workspace.xml`

Ignored files are tracked in a special file named `.gitignore` that is checked in at the root of your repository. There is no explicit git ignore command: instead the `.gitignore` file must be edited and committed by hand when you have new files that you wish to ignore. `.gitignore` files contain patterns that are matched against file names in your repository to determine whether or not they should be ignored. Here is a [sample`.gitignore`](https://gist.github.com/Azuritul/1139184) file.
For more details look at this [link](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/gitignore)

Answer (score 5):

#### Main purpose of .gitignore – so you avoid adding irrelevant files etc. Git

I have a lot of personal notes / scribbles in certain repositories: they are useful to me but not for anyone else. I would not want it uploaded to github because it would simply confuse everyone who read it. The good thing is that I can ask git to "ignore" those files. The only cost to this approach is that I will not be able to recover those notes if my computer crashes etc.

Answer (score 2):

The **.gitignore** file is a text file that instructs Git to ignore certain files or folders in a project.
A local **.gitignore** file is normally kept in the project's root directory. You can also create a global **.gitignore** file, which will be ignored in all of your Git repositories if any entries in it are found.
To create a local **.gitignore** file, create a text file and name it **.gitignore** (remember to include the . at the beginning). Then edit this file as needed. Each new line should list an additional file or folder that you want Git to ignore.

The entries in this file can also follow a matching pattern.

`*` is used as a wildcard match
`/` is used to ignore pathnames relative to the .gitignore file
`#` is used to add comments to a .gitignore file

Comment: Hello and Welcome to StackOverflow. Your answers is precise, concise and to the point. Links to the official documentation may improve it even more.

Answer (score -1):

The git ignore file rule allows you to ignore a file you've committed in the past. You use it when you do not want to recommit a file. basically
It's a list of files you want git to ignore in your work directory.