# GIT - Adding Java EE Full Application to Repository

Tags: git, jakarta-ee, github

I'm very new to GIT and I've been trying to add my Java EE application that I'm currently working on to the repository. So I first created a repository on bitbucket and cloned it through my terminal in my local machine. Then I copy pasted my Application Folder(name: bankingApp) inside the local repository. After that I did "git add bankingApp" and then commited and pushed. Inside the bankingApp folder there are five other folders, all folders gets added to my remote repository except two(my EJB folder and EE folder). When I try to commit this is what i get

modified:   BankingWebApp/BankingApplicationEE (untracked content)
modified:   BankingWebApp/BankingApplicationEJB (modified content, untracked content)

[image]

Can some please tell me what I need to do to add my whole application to bitbucket.

Comment: What tools do you use to work with git - cmd-line or software like GitKraken? Do you see which files are __tracked__ and which are __untracked__ - then please tell us which ones are __untracked__.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing files/directories seem to be part of your gitignore-file. This textfile is normally hidden and located in the top root of your git-repository. You should edit this file and remove these entries. Normally your gitignore-file lists file-extensions `git add - A` should ignore. Your missing files could match these file-extensions.

Have a look at: [what is gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850222/what-is-gitignore-exactly/27850270)

Be aware of unignoring file-extensions.  This possibly results in blowing up your git-repo in case these files are autogenerated, binary-files or the result of compiling your application. The idea behind Git is to version text-files - not binaries.

Comment: there is no such file in my repository

Comment: What is your operating system? In case your OS is Unix based (like OS X or Linux) you should navigate in your terminal to your local git repo (cd-command) and then type ls -l -a to list all files including the hidden ones. The name of the file is .gitignore. If you are not familar to vim use nano to open it: nano .gitignore. In the creating process of a repository on GitHub you have the possibility to choose a programming language. This information is used by GitHub to autogenrate a gitignore-file. I'm not familar to BitBucket. But maybe it generates this file, too.