# How to avoid a folder being pushed to the git repo

Tags: git

I have a folder and I don't want to push that folder into the git repo when I do `git add .`, commit and push my work.
Is there a way to avoid that folder getting pushed to the repo?
How can I do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is .gitignore exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850222/what-is-gitignore-exactly)

Answer (score 2):

just add it to .gitignore like this:

```
# dependencies
/node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.gitignore` file in the root folder,
and simply put the name of the file/folder you don't want to track in it.

Check [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) for more.