# How do I prevent .gitlab-ci.yml to be deleted when I push code to GitLab with GitKraken?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitkraken

I am new to GitLab. I have configured .gitlab-ci.yml via the GitLab interface. So .gitlab-ci.yml is not on my local machine. When I now push the code from my local machine to the repository on GitLab, .gitlab-ci.yml is deleted. I added .gitlab-ci.yml to .gitignore on both my local machine and GitLab, but the file still gets deleted. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

.gitlab-ci.yml should be committed to your source control. It shouldn't be in [.gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850222/what-is-gitignore-exactly/27850270).

Remove it from .gitignore, add it and commit

`git add .gitlab-ci.yml`