# Why does GitHub create a .gitignore folder? bug or feature?

Tags: github, gitignore

I create a new repository (empty) using the GitHub webclient and then add a .gitignore using the Getting Started screen and choose a template.
When I commit the file, it creates the .gitignore file inside a .gitignore folder.

```
reponame/.gitignore/.gitignore
```

But when I set the gitignore with a template on the "Create a new repository" screen it will be just the .gitignore file in the root folder.

```
reponame/.gitignore
```

I'm relatively new to the gitignore concept so I would like to know, is this a bug or a feature I'm not aware of?

Comment: Already answer : [Answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27850270/17113349)

Comment: @Biboune not quite, that question is about the file. The OP is asking about a *folder*