# Visual Studio Code - Source Control > 10k changes

Tags: javascript, git, visual-studio-code, source-control-explorer

Im new to programming as well as Git.
When opening a Git repository in Visual Studio Code that I created myself I've noticed my source control panel telling me that there is above 10k changes made, its in User/Gitfolder (MAC M1). Im the only one in this repository and haven't made any changes to it. What may be the problem?

When opening VSC I get a small warning window with the text "The git repository at '/Users/username' has too many active changes, only a subset of Git features will be enabled"

[image]

Comment: What kind of changes? End-of-line style? File encoding? File permissions?

Comment: Hi Alvaro, I edited the post hopefully highlighting my issues further, as I'm new to programming I'm not quite sure if it is enough clarification :)

Comment: You probably need to configure your [.gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850222/what-is-gitignore-exactly) file.

Comment: Looks like you don't exclude node_modules from git. Inspect and edit your .gitignore file.

Comment: If you leave your mouse pointer over the "U" you'll see a tooltip that explains it means "Untracked". Those are brand new files. I can't see the full paths but stuff like the `.vscode/` directory does normally not belong to your code and needs to be excluded from version control.

Comment: Thank you all for your advice! I'll look into this when I come home and edit the post as solved if I manage to fix it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By some reasons git is tracking the files in your /user/username folder. In your file explorer enter in to '/Users/username' folder. From the view option in window ribon bar check 'hidden item' option. when all hidden items appears delete the .git folder.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue just recently. It solved itself once I initialized the project folder as a git repository with the `git init`.

If it was already initialized make sure you are in the correct project folder and if you are then display the hidden files and delete the .git folder.

Answer (score 1):

[%WSL UBUNTU] Happened to me.  I think when you opened your project in VS Code, you were in the root directory instead of a project folder further down your file system tree, so what you are seeing are the installations from your root folder being included in your VS Code workspace.

[If you need to rearrange your file system folders or create a projects folder, type 'explorer.exe .' in your linux terminal]

I would close VS Code instance, open your Linux Terminal and navigate to your projects folder: cd /home/'user name'/projects.  Then type 'code .'

A new VS Code workspace will open in the right directory and the git will not include those root repositories