# Python virtual environment and GitHub

Tags: python, github, virtualenv, gitignore, python-venv

I am building a website currently using a virtual environment. I noticed when I commit things to GitHub that the bar that shows the language usage ratio on GitHub is skewed to the point where the languages I'm actually using are barely represented due to the Python code in the virtual environment.

I tried deleting the virtual environment straight in GitHub but then when I went back to my last commit later on, I had to remake a new environment and move my file into that environment.

Is there any way to fix this? I feel like this is definitely something people have had to deal with before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850222/what-is-gitignore)

Comment: Destroy the repo by deleting the `.git` folder, then recreate it with `git init`, and add your virtual environment to the `.gitignore` file with the first commit. (and recreate the github repo as well)

Answer (score 0):

Add the name of the virtual environment folder to your `.gitignore` file. For example, if your virtual environment folder is named `venv`, add the following line to the `.gitignore` file:

```
venv/
```

Comment: You will also need to run `git rm -r --cached .` and `git add -A` to ignore what has already been committed